# PHP ssh->exec() Keep Alive util code completes its job

Tags: php, ssh, phpseclib

For sending campaign email we are using  ssh->exec but if mails are more than 10k means without any message its stops working

So I need to keep alive file running. How to fix?.

```
$ssh = new SSH2('example.com');

if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) {

 exceptionErrorHandler("Error logging in to server for " . $queue);
} else {
 $ssh->exec('php applications/root/public_html/includes/php/workers/' . $queue . '.php &');
}
```

Comment: Sure it stops working? How you checked this?

Comment: after 7k mails no logs, no exception, my script takes to complete 30mins to 1 hour, Can we use setTimout or keepAlive?

Comment: I would suggest chunk the mails beeing sent to a manageable size ... you are aware, that "&" sends the process to background? Whats the max execution time for your php config?

Comment: I'd try doing `$ssh->setTimeout(0)` first. That'll make it so that phpseclib won't close the connection. If that doesn't work then you could try tweaking `$ssh->setKeepAlive(5)` or whatever. That'll try to make it so that the server won't close the connection (in theory)